# case on css specificity

Tags: css

I have html like:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  color: red;
}

.my-a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header class="my-header">
  <div>
    <a class="my-a" href="https://www.google.com">clickme</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Then 'clickme' will be green as expected. And it follows the rule that class selectors has a greater specificity than type selectors.

But when css becomes:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.my-header a {
  color: red;
}

.my-a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header class="my-header">
  <div>
    <a class="my-a" href="https://www.google.com">clickme</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

The result shows that 'clickme' is red which is out of my expectation. I cannot find any corresponding rule in [MDN specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Am i missing any rule here? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzjoke/bsyxqomr/9/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.my-header a` is a type selector AND a class selector which is more specific than `.my-a` which is a class selector and nothing else.

Comment: I'm confused that MDN says that universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ') and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity.  What does it actually mean by saying combinators have no effect on specificity?

Comment: @39ecneret — `.my-header a` / `.my-header + a` / `.my-header :not(a)` / `:not(.my-header) > a` — all have a class selector and a type selector and have the same specificity. The combinators don't change the specificity. Just the selectors.